# IntelliSense for Python not working consistently

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have just installed the python development environment from within the `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise` installer (running version 15.9.5 which is latest as of now).

Here is some code snippet that I am currently working with.

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

[...]

# Sequential() provides a stack of layers
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

# ==> trying to use autocompletion here 
model.
```

I am wondering why I don't have `IntelliSense` support for the instance `model` but eg for `tf`. It seems that it's not working consistently.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

---

## Edit

I have already tried to refreh the IntelliSense database. However it always seems to freeze when it comes to analyzing the numpy library. This seems to be a know issue.

Microsoft is going to replace the IntelliSense database with the upcoming Visual Studio 2019. This is all well and good, but wont solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have an appropriate virtual environment activated?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, sorry thats not clear from my post. I try to autocomplete immediately under this code. Will update my question.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid, no I don't have any virtual environment activated.

Comment: Hi, you can also seek for a better support from https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues